# How to Solve Java selenium error in testing?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am new in software testing and following this course from utest.com 
https://www.utest.com/courses/selenium-basics-part-4-create-java-project-add-recorded-test-case-run-project
when following steps while the instructor was testing the code the test case worked with him and give me error as in this photo 
[screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bSU0.png)

how can i solve it ?

Comment: If you really want a solution, please share your code and error here instead of screenshot...

Comment: I shared it in the post in (Screen shot in the erorr)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that your selenium server is up and running on your localhost port 4444. Checking for example `http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=getLogMessages`

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the screen shot attached, the error might be because of below mentioned reasons

1) Selenium Server Standalone file is not properly configured, make sure you use the correct version of the file that is compatible with your local system

2) There might be chance that the port has been occupied by some other process, make sure the port which listens to Selenium Server Standalone is free or u can forcefully assign some other port which is not occupied to Selenium Server Standalone

Hope this will work